# Android start an activity inside SMSmanager

Tags: android

I would like to ask if i can start an activity from SmsManager especially from sendTextMessage() or if i can use the context.sendBroadcast() function. I would like somehow to send a custom intent when i try to send a message.

Can i do something about this.

Comment: To clarify, you are asking how to detect when the device tries to send a message?

Comment: Yes...but i would like somehow to trigger an alertdialog

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but it's somewhat unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish. sendTextMessage simply sends a text message. What could adding an extra intent or broadcast to that process achieve?

Why would you want to start an activity "from" sendTextMessage()? Why not just send the text message, and then start the new activity afterward?

Comment: Because i make some checks before sms sending. I would like somehow to trigger i alertdialog before sms sending.

Comment: so then, perform your checks, trigger the alertdialog and in the ondismiss (or better yet, the onclick of the positive button) of the dialog, send the sms

Comment: How can i trigger this alertDialog? i am not inside an activity

Comment: where are you creating the SmsManager from? When are you doing all this?

Comment: I want to do this stuff in default android source code of SmsManager and not to an new application

Comment: I'm sorry...you're not trying to write an application? Are you trying to write your own android rom?

Comment: Exactly. I am new in this area.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. For rom development questions I'd recommend http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=613

Comment: So can i use context.sendBroadcast() from inside default SmsManager ?

Comment: I'm not a rom developer, but what I'd assume is you have 2 options. Either modify SmsManager to have it be able to accept a context. **OR** modify all activities in android which call SmsManager to perform the broadcasts there.